# re: binary random-eff meta-analysis: Why is my heterogeneity estimate so much higher using GLMM compared to other methods? (metabin function)

Tags: r, meta-analysis, heterogeneity, metafor

I am trying to conduct a random effects meta-analysis for binary outcome data using the GLMM method in the meta package (metabin function / meta package).

meta package citation:
Balduzzi S, Rücker G, Schwarzer G (2019). “How to perform a meta-analysis with R: a practical tutorial.” Evidence-Based Mental Health, 153–160.https://doi.org/10.1136/ebmental-2019-300117

metafor package citation (rma.glmm called internally):
Viechtbauer, W. (2010). Conducting meta-analyses in R with the metafor package.Journal of Statistical Software, 36(3), 1-48. https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v036.i03

**I am perplexed about why the heterogeneity estimate is so much higher for GLMM than what I get using other methods (Mantel-Haenszel or Inverse variance). Does anyone know why this might be?** I am not sure if it is a coding error on my part or whether there's another explanation for this. I created a dummy dataset that replicates the pattern of findings from my data ("Data1" below). I also attached my output.

The OR estimates were similar across models, but the heterogeneity for GLMM is much larger (albeit, with a very large confidence interval)

**OR estimates:**

- GLMM: 1.13
- MH: 1.12
- Inverse-variance: 1.12

**I^2 estimates:**

- GLMM: 53.6% [95% CI: 5.3%; 77.3%]
- MH: 0.0% [95% CI: 0.0%; 62.4%]
- Inverse-variance: 0.0% [95% CI: 0.0%; 62.4%]

**dummy data:**

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
Ne <- c(30,20,15,65,20,10,20,20,55,46)
Ee <- c(2,2,2,21,2,2,3,6,22,10)
Nc <- c(30,9,14,68,10,10,10,15,50,25)
Ec <- c(3,3,1,15,2,0,2,3,19,6)
Data1 <- data.frame(ID,Ne,Ee,Nc,Ec)
```

**GLMM code and output:**

```
m.bin.glmm <- metabin(event.e = Ee, 
                      n.e = Ne,
                      event.c = Ec,
                      n.c = Nc,
                      studlab = ID,
                      data = Data1,
                      sm = "OR",
                      method = "GLMM",
                      fixed = FALSE,
                      random = TRUE,
                      method.tau = "ML",
                      method.incr = "only0",
                      model.glmm = "UM.RS",
                      method.random.ci = TRUE,
                      title = "test")
summary(m.bin.glmm)

Warning message:
Not possible to fit RE/ME model='UM.RS' with nAGQ > 1 with glmer(). nAGQ automatically set to 1. 
> summary(m.bin.glmm)
Review:     test

       OR             95%-CI
1  0.6429 [0.0995;   4.1530]
2  0.2222 [0.0297;   1.6646]
3  2.0000 [0.1608;  24.8709]
4  1.6864 [0.7778;   3.6561]
5  0.4444 [0.0528;   3.7383]
6  6.1765 [0.2599; 146.7771]
7  0.7059 [0.0978;   5.0957]
8  1.7143 [0.3510;   8.3725]
9  1.0877 [0.4958;   2.3861]
10 0.8796 [0.2772;   2.7911]

Number of studies combined: k = 10
Number of observations: o = 542
Number of events: e = 126

                         OR           95%-CI    t p-value
Random effects model 1.1340 [0.7041; 1.8262] 0.60  0.5653

Quantifying heterogeneity:
 tau^2 = 0; tau = 0; I^2 = 53.6% [5.3%; 77.3%]; H = 1.47 [1.03; 2.10]

Test of heterogeneity:
     Q d.f. p-value             Test
 19.41    9  0.0219        Wald-type
 10.16    9  0.3381 Likelihood-Ratio

Details on meta-analytical method:
- Mixed-effects logistic regression model (random study effects)
- Maximum-likelihood estimator for tau^2
- Random effects confidence interval based on t-distribution (df = 9)
- Continuity correction of 0.5 in studies with zero cell frequencies
  (only used to calculate individual study results)
```

**Mantel-Haenszel code and output:**

```
m.bin_MH <- metabin(event.e = Ee, 
                         n.e = Ne,
                         event.c = Ec,
                         n.c = Nc,
                         studlab = ID,
                         data = Data1,
                         sm = "OR",
                         method = "MH",
                         fixed = FALSE,
                         random = TRUE,
                         method.tau = "DL",
                         method.incr = "only0",
                         Q.Cochrane = TRUE,
                         #  model.glmm = "UM.RS",
                         method.random.ci = TRUE,
                         title = "test")
summary(m.bin_MH)

Review:     test

       OR             95%-CI %W(random)
1  0.6429 [0.0995;   4.1530]        5.0
2  0.2222 [0.0297;   1.6646]        4.3
3  2.0000 [0.1608;  24.8709]        2.8
4  1.6864 [0.7778;   3.6561]       29.3
5  0.4444 [0.0528;   3.7383]        3.9
6  6.1765 [0.2599; 146.7771]        1.7
7  0.7059 [0.0978;   5.0957]        4.5
8  1.7143 [0.3510;   8.3725]        7.0
9  1.0877 [0.4958;   2.3861]       28.4
10 0.8796 [0.2772;   2.7911]       13.1

Number of studies combined: k = 10
Number of observations: o = 542
Number of events: e = 126

                         OR           95%-CI    t p-value
Random effects model 1.1210 [0.7413; 1.6953] 0.62  0.5477

Quantifying heterogeneity:
 tau^2 = 0; tau = 0; I^2 = 0.0% [0.0%; 62.4%]; H = 1.00 [1.00; 1.63]

Test of heterogeneity:
    Q d.f. p-value
 6.60    9  0.6788

Details on meta-analytical method:
- Mantel-Haenszel method
- DerSimonian-Laird estimator for tau^2
- Mantel-Haenszel estimator used in calculation of Q and tau^2 (like RevMan 5)
- Hartung-Knapp (HK) adjustment for random effects model (df = 9)
- Continuity correction of 0.5 in studies with zero cell frequencies
```

**Inverse-variance code and output:**

```
m.bin_Inv <- metabin(event.e = Ee, 
                         n.e = Ne,
                         event.c = Ec,
                         n.c = Nc,
                         studlab = ID,
                         data = Data1,
                         sm = "OR",
                         method = "Inverse",
                         fixed = FALSE,
                         random = TRUE,
                         method.tau = "DL",
                         method.incr = "only0",
                         #  model.glmm = "UM.RS",
                         method.random.ci = TRUE,
                         title = "test")
summary(m.bin_Inv)

Review:     test

       OR             95%-CI %W(random)
1  0.6429 [0.0995;   4.1530]        5.0
2  0.2222 [0.0297;   1.6646]        4.3
3  2.0000 [0.1608;  24.8709]        2.8
4  1.6864 [0.7778;   3.6561]       29.3
5  0.4444 [0.0528;   3.7383]        3.9
6  6.1765 [0.2599; 146.7771]        1.7
7  0.7059 [0.0978;   5.0957]        4.5
8  1.7143 [0.3510;   8.3725]        7.0
9  1.0877 [0.4958;   2.3861]       28.4
10 0.8796 [0.2772;   2.7911]       13.1

Number of studies combined: k = 10
Number of observations: o = 542
Number of events: e = 126

                         OR           95%-CI    t p-value
Random effects model 1.1210 [0.7413; 1.6953] 0.62  0.5477

Quantifying heterogeneity:
 tau^2 = 0 [0.0000; 1.1907]; tau = 0 [0.0000; 1.0912]
 I^2 = 0.0% [0.0%; 62.4%]; H = 1.00 [1.00; 1.63]

Test of heterogeneity:
    Q d.f. p-value
 6.60    9  0.6792

Details on meta-analytical method:
- Inverse variance method
- DerSimonian-Laird estimator for tau^2
- Jackson method for confidence interval of tau^2 and tau
- Hartung-Knapp (HK) adjustment for random effects model (df = 9)
- Continuity correction of 0.5 in studies with zero cell frequencies
```

Comment: metabin is not in the metafor package.

Comment: Yes - good point. Sorry for causing confusion - however, a function from the metafor package is used: "For GLMMs, the rma.glmm function from R package metafor (Viechtbauer, 2010) is called internally" (https://rdrr.io/cran/meta/man/metabin.html)

Comment: thanks for pointing this out - I edited the attributions to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the heterogeneity diverges pretty strongly between the three methods in terms of $I^2$. However, when you are looking at the estimates of heterogeneity in terms of standard deviation or variance (tau = $\tau$ or tau^2 = $\tau^2$), all three models come to the same estimate (0). Tau aims to estimate the actual spread/dispersion of parameters in the statistical population that you assess, free of sampling error. $I^2$ on the other hand is a relative measure of $I^2 = \frac{\tau^2}{\tau^2 + \nu} \cdot 100\%$. Parameter $\nu$ describes the expected within-study random sampling variance. Since the $\tau$-estimates seem to be (nearly) identical across all three methods, it appears that the estimated $\nu$-values differ more strongly. Since $\tau$ is probably not exactly zero, but pretty close to it, if $\nu$ differs substantially large, huge differences in $I^2$ may not be surprising. In terms of actual spread of population parameters, the studies all seem to come to similar conclusions.